# magento 2 - class error on backend after remover facebook-for-magento

Tags: magento2, class, facebook

I'm Newbie, after remove facebook for magento now encounter error. magento backend catalog-products unable to load.

**There has been an error processing your request
Class Facebook\BusinessExtension\Model\Config\Source\Product\GoogleProductCategory does not exist**

already clear cache files using -> php bin/magento cache:enable,

can someone guide me how to solve this. exactly which file to be edit and how.

[image][image]

Comment: could i know how to solve this
i couldnt find any thing in eva_attribute related to (facebook and google)
do i should delet all eva_attribute or what?

Answer (score 4):

`Facebook\BusinessExtension\Model\Config\Source\Product\GoogleProductCategory` could be used for custom attribute option source.

Please search in  `eav_attribute` table, especially in `source_model` column.

According to file:
`https://github.com/facebookincubator/facebook-for-magento2/blob/master/Setup/UpgradeData.php#L138` this is the issue you are facing. To avoid issues like that in the future, scan your code for that class name and make sure you clear custom attributes too.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved after delete the attribuite. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must delete every element with meta, facebook and google inside , like these

137 |              3 | sync_to_facebook_catalog       | NULL                                                                                                                  138 |              3 | meta_product_set_id            | NULL
139 |              4 | google_product_category        | NULL
140 |              4 | send_to_facebook               | NULL